# VBA: Count the amount of different items are seleted in a filter

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, filter

In Excel I have a filter on a header, this filter allows the user to select different areas and show the records that match the areas selected. I have the following code that then displays the value that has been selected in the filter:

```
Dim ftrRegion As Filter
On Error GoTo stopError
Set ftrArea = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2)
Set ftrRegion = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)

If ftrRegion.On Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Debug.Print ftrRegion.Criteria1
    Range("E206").Value = Mid$(ftrRegion.Criteria1, 2)
    Range("F201").Value = "Region" & " " & Mid$(ftrRegion.Criteria1, 2)
Else
    Range("E206").Value = ""
End If
```

But the problem with this is that if a user selects more than one value the whole thing doesn't work, so what I want is a way to count the amount of values the user has selected in the filter, and if it is just the 1 then apply this code through an if statement. Can someone please help.

Comment: I don't know, can you show me how it would work please

Comment: I don't think it's what you need actually, removed the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
If ftrRegion.On Then
```

To

```
If ftrRegion.On And ftrRegion.Count = 1 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with recent versions of Office, but it may assist:

```
Function GetFilterSettings(oFilter As Filter) As String
   Dim sTemp           As String
   With oFilter
      If .On Then
         If IsArray(.Criteria1) Then
            sTemp = Join(.Criteria1, ", ")
         Else
            Select Case .Operator
               Case xlAnd
                  sTemp = .Criteria1
                  If Len(.Criteria2) > 0 Then _
                     sTemp = sTemp & " and " & .Criteria2
               Case xlBottom10Percent
                  sTemp = "Bottom n% - effectively" & .Criteria1
               Case xlTop10Items
                  sTemp = "Top n items - effectively " & .Criteria1
               Case xlBottom10Items
                  sTemp = "Bottom n items - effectively " & .Criteria1
               Case xlOr
                  sTemp = .Criteria1
                  If Len(.Criteria2) > 0 Then _
                     sTemp = sTemp & " or " & .Criteria2
               Case xlTop10Percent
                  sTemp = "Top n% - effectively " & .Criteria1
            End Select
         End If
      Else
         sTemp = "Off"
      End If
   End With
   GetFilterSettings = sTemp

End Function
```

So with that in a **normal module**, your code would become:

```
Dim ftrRegion As Filter
On Error GoTo stopError
Set ftrArea = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2)
Set ftrRegion = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("E206").Value = GetFilterSettings(ftrArea)
    Range("F201").Value = "Region " & GetFilterSettings(ftrRegion)
```